# Get the sizeof() correctly

Tags: c++, arduino

I have several byte arrays and an array of the byte arrays. I want to get the size of a byte array from the last array (the array of byte arrays). `sizeof()` works good on a byte array but it does not when I try to index the array with the byte arrays.

```
byte A[]={B01111110,B10001000,B10001000,B10001000,B01111110};
byte B[]={B11111110,B10010010,B10010010,B10010010,B01101100};
byte gamma[]={B11111110,B10000000,B10000000,B10000000,B10000000};

byte *test[]={A,B,gamma}

Serial.println(sizeof(gamma));
Serial.println(sizeof(test[2]));
```

The first serial print gives `5` that is correct the second gives `2` (probably the size of the pointer).

How can I get the correct result cause I want to use the `test[i]` in a for loop.

I read that I should declare `*test[]` as `test[][]` in order not to get the size  of the pointer but I get an error of assigning a `byte*` to a `byte`.

Comment: You have to keep track of the size. Or use container types that do that for you.

Answer (score 1):

You may use:

```
byte (*(test[3]))[5]={&A, &B, &gamma};

static_assert(5 == sizeof(*test[0]), "unexpected size");
```

But using `std::vector` would be simpler.

if the sizes of different arrays are different, you have to provide a way to know the size:

- Provide a sentinel value (as `'\0'` for C-string)
- Give the length/size along the pointer, something like:

  ```
  std::pair<byte*, std::size_t> tests[] = {
      {A, sizeof(A)},
      {B, sizeof(B)},
      {gamma, sizeof(gamma)}
  };
  ```

Comment: Arduino from what i know though it is c/c++ does now use vectors.This was my first thought. the size of all the byte arrays is not 5 some are 6 some are 2 etc. can i skip the size declaration?

Comment: @kyrpav: the first solution doesn't handle different size, I edited my answer to provide alternative solution.

Comment: @kyrpav please do a favor to your microcontroller's memory and keep track of every array size. The simplest thing to do is just have
`byte *A = {0x01, 0x02, 0x22}; int length_of_A = 3`. This way you will never corrupt the memory....